# Where Can I host My Locahost Project For Free To Put On The Web?

Tags: localhost, hosting

I just finished a long project and would like to display on the web.

I'm looking for a site that will let me host for free; obviously right now I'm not trying to buy a domain name, I just want to be able to see my project on the web and not just in my localhost.

Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's not confused the domain with the host. The host is the server where your project will be, in the way that everyone can reach him acessing a specific ip address made available by the host.

Domain is the name your dns service will convert to. From ip to domain. To get a domain, there is specific websites, but i will not go in detail since is not your gold.

You can host your project for free in this web site: https://www.000webhost.com/

Please, if you found this comment useful do not forget to up vote.

Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways for hosting site , you can try 30 day trial of azure VM or u can try AWS 30 day trial.